# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Server Fault's [sixth moderator election](https://serverfault.com/election/6) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Ward] [image: yagmoth555]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://serverfault.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking EEAA and HBruijn who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://serverfault.com/election/6), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6291206518603776/0).

Comment: Woohoo!  Congrats, Ward and yagmoth555!  Ward, it's about time!

Answer (score 22):

Congratulations to @Ward and @yagmoth555 have fun!

Thanks to @HBruijn and @EEAA for your moderation (in all senses).

Comment: Thanks... just handled my first flag, yay!

Comment: @Ward hope you don't stop voting.  You've always been my voting hero!

Answer (score 5):

I totally missed this. Completely. My bad!

Ward is the perfect example of why you should never stop trying. Every single election they've been nominated and after 7 years and 6 attempts that absolutely insane number of votes cast has paid off.

Answer (score 1):

Moderator, it is not a "celebrity", it is a hard work, and it means to have skin in the game.

I wish them good luck, reliable keyboard, and full cup of coffee by hand.